# How to compare two arrays which consist of dates and remove the date if it is same, and then add next date to that array...?

Tags: jquery, momentjs

```js
var dateList = ["01-01-2018",
  "14-01-2018",

  "26-01-2018",

  "14-02-2018",

  "02-03-2018",

  "18-03-2018",

  "25-03-2018",

  "29-03-2018",

  "30-03-2018",

  "30-04-2018",

  "01-05-2018"
];



console.log(dateList);



var quickList = ["30-04-2018", "01-05-2018"];



for (var i = 0; i < quickList.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < dateList.length; j++) {
    if (quickList[i] == dateList[j]) {
      var tempNextDay = moment(quickList[i], "DD-MM-YYYY");
      var nextDay = moment(tempNextDay).add(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
      quickList.push(nextDay);
      quickList.splice(i, 1);

      i = 0;
      break;
    }

  }
}
console.log(quickList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/locale/af.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The quickList consist of two dates which is also in the dateList. I want to remove the quickList dates which matches the dateList and also add next date to the holiday. But It always remove only the first Element in array...? Someone please help me.... Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
var dateList = ["01-01-2018",
  "14-01-2018",

  "26-01-2018",

  "14-02-2018",

  "02-03-2018",

  "18-03-2018",

  "25-03-2018",

  "29-03-2018",

  "30-03-2018",

  "30-04-2018",

  "01-05-2018"
];



console.log(dateList);



var quickList = ["30-04-2018", "01-05-2018"];



for (var i = 0; i < quickList.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < dateList.length; j++) {
    if (quickList[i] == dateList[j]) {
      var tempNextDay = moment(quickList[i], "DD-MM-YYYY");
      var nextDay = moment(tempNextDay).add(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
      quickList.push(nextDay);
      quickList.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
console.log(quickList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/locale/af.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Ranjith , you have mistakenly do i=0 in your loop so it is not executing furthur

Comment: hi bro, if i did not put i=0 then it will not execute the newly inserted date. So i will get the same date response again....

Comment: You also getting the same response, I want to get output as  ["02-05-2018","03-05-2018"]. In your output the "01-05-2018" is listed but it is in the dateList. So it will be deleted and then the result array will be injected with new next date....